# Filtering with either on-demand paging or virtual scrolling for Syncfusion GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, filtering, syncfusion

I am using Syncfusion ASP.NET GridView for loading large data. It needs features of filtering, paging, editing. Now, the problem is with paging as it takes quite a bit of time. So, I switched to on-demand paging but the problem with that is, it applies filters to only the current page records. So, searched of virtual scrolling but it is not available.

Of course, the combination is available in Syncfusion ASP.NET MVC. But I need this for ASP.NET only.

Also, using a stored procedure is not an option as that would also use up a lot of time every time the filter is applied or paging is done.

Is there a solution for this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Syncfusion ASP Grid currently does not support Filtering in On-demand paging. You can sort the whole datasource  by doing workaround but filtering is not supported yet.

Even in our project when the same kind of situation arisen, we switched to external filtering option and we had contacted the support and asked them to log this as a feature in their library.

All you can do now is the same as it will get high priority when several customers need the feature and they may implement soon. And they now have **consulting option** where you can ask them to deliver feature immediately by **paying extra bucks** for this.

Comment: Thanks for the response! We're considering it now.